# SAS-Problems in data import

Tags: import, sas

I used following code to import data from csv format into SAS. However, the data in the created dataset is in wrong row as shown in the pic. The actual data in bid size is located in bid_price and the data in bid_size is missing. Due to some reason, I cannot use File>Import data or `proc import`. Hence, could anyone help me check the code I used?

[image]

```
data WORK.want   ;
       %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
       infile "E:\N69853943.csv"                                                                 /*obs = 10*/
       delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2 ;
          informat _RIC $25. ;
          informat Date_L_ best32. ;
          informat Time_L_ time20.3 ;
          informat Type $13. ;
          informat Ex_Cntrb_ID $1. ;
          informat LOC $1. ;
          informat Price best32. ;
          informat Volume best32. ;
          informat Market_VWAP $1. ;
          informat Buyer_ID $3. ;
          informat Bid_Price best32. ;
          informat Bid_Size best32. ;
          informat No__Buyers $1. ;
          informat Seller_ID $3. ;
          informat Ask_Price best32. ;
          informat Ask_Size best32. ;

          format _RIC $25. ;
          format Date_L_ best32. ;
          format Time_L_ time20.3 ;
          format Type $13. ;
          format Ex_Cntrb_ID $1. ;
          format LOC $1. ;
          format Price best32. ;
          format Volume best32. ;
          format Market_VWAP $1. ;
          format Buyer_ID $3. ;
          format Bid_Price best32. ;
          format Bid_Size best32. ;
          format No__Buyers $1. ;
          format Seller_ID $3. ;
          format Ask_Price best32. ;
          format Ask_Size best32. ;

       input
                   _RIC $
                   Date_L_
                   Time_L_
                   Type $
                   Ex_Cntrb_ID $
                   LOC $
                   Price
                   Volume
                   Market_VWAP $
                   Buyer_ID $
                   Bid_Price
                   Bid_Size
                   No__Buyers $
                   Seller_ID $
                   Ask_Price
                   Ask_Size
                              ;
       if _ERROR_ then call symputx('_EFIERR_',1);  /* set ERROR detection macro variable */

run;
```

Comment: Change MISSOVER to TRUNCOVER and verify your file layout structure? Are the variables where SAS thinks they are? Note that the code above looks like the automatically generated code from a PROC IMPORT step. If so, re-run the PROC IMPORT on the CSV and set GUESSINGROWS really high so it sets lengths and types later.

Comment: Note that your INPUT shows a LOC variable, between columns E/F. Does that variable have a comma in the name? or is the / causing issues? We can't see the full name so I can't comment beyond that.

Comment: That's clearly the problem (the LOC), I'd suggest posting that as an answer @Reeza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has an extra variable, LOC, listed compared to the Excel file and thus your data is pushed over one field. It's between column E/F.

Note that the variable right before, is cut off for presentation but it has a / and may have a comma which caused PROC IMPORT to assume you had another variable. Remove the LOC variable to read the file in correctly.

You may also want to use the TRUNCOVER instead of MISSOVER.